# Object moving on x axis integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So, I think I know how to set up this problem, but then I get stuck at the last part:

An object moves along the x - axis such that its velocity at time $t$ is $v(t) = cos(2t) $. Suppose the object starts at $x= 1$ and $t = 0$. Find its coordinate $x(t)$ at time $t$

This is what I have so far:

$$\begin{align*}\int^t_0 V(z) \, \mathrm{d}z &= \int^t_0 \cos(2z) \, \mathrm{d}z \\&=\frac{1}{2} \sin(2t) - \frac{1}{2} \sin(0) \\&=\frac{1}{2} \sin(2t)\end{align*}$$

and from here I get stuck. How do I find the coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

It should be $x(t) = x(0) + \displaystyle \int_{0}^t v(z)dz = 1 + \dfrac{\sin (2t)}{2}$